# Prove "proof by contradiction" from $L_0$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, sequent-calculus

Basically, I was reading the comments to [Equivalence of Deductive System $L_0$ and the Sequent Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754794/equivalence-of-deductive-system-l-0-and-the-sequent-calculus) and Mauro says that PC is A3 in sequent form. I don't quite understand this. Can someone please explain me how can PC be deduced from $L_0$?

Comment: You are right: a little bit too short as explanation... [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764637/hilbert-style-proof-of-double-negation-introduction-and-reductio-ab-adsurdum) you can find how to derive Hilbert-style PC from Transposition (A3).